# Want to push some key value pair to a nested object

Tags: angularjs, arrays

Object: 1

```
{
    "sourcePath": "vv",
    "targetPath": "bb"
}
```

I'm get a key value pair like Object 1 and already I have a nested object like Object 2

Object : 2

```
{
"user": "hdpsrvc",
"update": "13/06/2016 17:43:22",
"template": "template_1",
"formBody": [
    {
        "tabIndex": 0,
        "type": "text",
        "name": "sourcePath",
        "label": "Source path"
    },
    {
        "tabIndex": 1,
        "type": "text",
        "name": "targetPath",
        "label": "Target path"
    }
],
```

}

and I want to push the key value pair of Object 1 into a nested object like below (please see the red mark bold key value pair under `formBody`)

```
{
"user": "hdpsrvc",
"update": "13/06/2016 17:43:22",
"template": "template_1",
"formBody": [
    {
        "tabIndex": 0,
        "type": "text",
        "name": "sourcePath",
        "label": "Source path",
        "sourcePath": "vv"
    },
    {
        "tabIndex": 1,
        "type": "text",
        "name": "targetPath",
        "label": "Target path",
        "targetPath": "bb"
    }
],
}
```

Comment: This does not seem related to JSON, but to JavaScript objects. Please read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only these two valus to push then it can be easy done by simply assign as below.

Assuming JSON 1 is store in varible `var jsonOne` and JSON 2 is store in varible `var jsonTwo`. Then

```
jsonTwo.formBody[0].sourcePath = jsonOne.sourcePath;
jsonTwo.formBody[1].targetPath = jsonOne.targetPath;
```

Or if you have more values to push then you can write a for loop and form an algorithm to match. In below code I'am matching with label;

```
for (i = 0; i < jsonTwo.formBody.length; i++) {
    var temp = jsonTwo.formBody[i].label;
    if (temp === 'Source path') {
        jsonTwo.formBody[i].sourcePath = jsonOne.sourcePath;
    } else {
        jsonTwo.formBody[i].targetPath = jsonOne.targetPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```js
var obj1 = {
    "sourcePath": "vv",
    "targetPath": "bb"
};

var obj2 = {
"user": "hdpsrvc",
"update": "13/06/2016 17:43:22",
"template": "template_1",
"formBody": [
    {
        "tabIndex": 0,
        "type": "text",
        "name": "sourcePath",
        "label": "Source path"
    },
    {
        "tabIndex": 1,
        "type": "text",
        "name": "targetPath",
        "label": "Target path"
    }
]};

obj2.formBody = obj2.formBody.map((item , ind) => Object.assign(
  item,
  {[Object.keys(obj1)[ind]]: obj1[Object.keys(obj1)[ind]]}
));
console.log(obj2);
```

or even:

```js
var obj1 = {
    "sourcePath": "vv",
    "targetPath": "bb"
};

var obj2 = {
"user": "hdpsrvc",
"update": "13/06/2016 17:43:22",
"template": "template_1",
"formBody": [
    {
        "tabIndex": 0,
        "type": "text",
        "name": "sourcePath",
        "label": "Source path"
    },
    {
        "tabIndex": 1,
        "type": "text",
        "name": "targetPath",
        "label": "Target path"
    }
]};

obj2.formBody = obj2.formBody.map(item => Object.assign(
  item,
  {[item.name]: obj1[item.name]}
));
console.log(obj2);
```